# Decode array in python in a function

Tags: python, decode

I created a load function to read a file. My  problem is that the data is an array that I need to decode.

```
def load(input_file):
    f = open(input_file,"rb")
    if f.mode == "rb":
       contents = f.read()
       print(contents)

load('/path/data/text.txt')
```

The results is the following that I need to decode

```
b'\xc3\x84\x03cjoblib.numpy_pickle\nNumpyArrayWrapper\nq\x00)\
    xc3\x85q\x01}q\x02(X\x08\x00\x00\x00subclassq
    \x03cnumpy\nndarray\nq\x04X\x05\x00\x00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your file contains [`pickle`'d data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

Assuming you trust the file, then you can load it with `pickle.load`:

```
arr = pickle.loads(content)
```

However, please be aware that loading pickled content is *super* dangerous, so make sure you can absolutely trust the file (e.g., you know that *you* created it and it has not been modified) before loading it).

`pickle` *can* be useful in certain cases, such as sharing data between two separate Python processes.

Another option: since it looks like you're storing a `numpy` array, it would be better and easier (maybe faster) to use `numpy`'s [`tofile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) function.

```
arr = numpy.arange(10)
arr.tofile('array.bin')

loaded_arr = numpy.fromfile('array.bin', numpy.int)
```

Comment: Thanks Nikolas. The last line "loaded_arr = numpy.fromfile()" is not clear. Why a "tofile" at first and then a "fromfile"? Also what is numpy.init? Sorry, but I am not familiar with this.

Comment: No problem, @Annalix! `tofile` and `fromfile` are meant to show two different things: 1) how you would _save_ an array to file (`tofile`), and then how you could later _load_ that same array back from the file (`fromfile`). `numpy.int` specifies the data type, without it, numpy assumes the values are floating-point. In your case, you'd have to know the data type of your array and use that.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nicholas. It is a numpy array actually and it does seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the data is a Python pickle, you should use the [pickle module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.load) for loading it

```
pickle.load(input_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing out on the conditional and not entering it.
contents should be under the `if` statement

```py
def load(input_file):
    f = open(input_file,"rb")
    if f.mode == "rb":
        contents = f.read()
        print(contents)

load('/path/data/text.txt')
```

Comment: yes you are right. Don't trust the indentation of the script here, in the code is correct